# How to connect IntelliJ's Docker plugin to Docker Desktop Windows

Tags: docker, intellij-idea, windows-10

I'm running the latest Windows 10 Pro build (1903), the latest Docker Engine build (v19.03.8), and the latest IntelliJ (2019.3.4). I have set *Expose daemon on `tcp://localhost:2375` without TLS* and Apply/Restart-ed the Engine. Trying to switch to a Windows container seemingly hangs the daemon, throwing an error, after which I need to destroy all settings and config files before I can start the daemon again.

Yet, when I'm trying to set `tcp://localhost:2375` in my Docker plugin, the connection simply fails (probably with a timeout, but there's no log of it). Yet, simply using `docker info` and other commands from the CLI works as intended, so I'm fairly certain the Engine is running.
For reference, the output of `docker info`:

```
$ docker system info
Client:
 Debug Mode: false
 Plugins:
  app: Docker Application (Docker Inc., v0.8.0)
  buildx: Build with BuildKit (Docker Inc., v0.3.1-tp-docker)

Server:
 Containers: 0
  Running: 0
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 0
 Images: 0
 Server Version: 19.03.8
 Storage Driver: overlay2
  Backing Filesystem: <unknown>
  Supports d_type: true
  Native Overlay Diff: true
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
  Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Runtimes: runc
 Default Runtime: runc
 Init Binary: docker-init
 containerd version: 7ad184331fa3e55e52b890ea95e65ba581ae3429
 runc version: dc9208a3303feef5b3839f4323d9beb36df0a9dd
 init version: fec3683
 Security Options:
  seccomp
   Profile: default
 Kernel Version: 4.19.76-linuxkit
 Operating System: Docker Desktop
 OSType: linux
 Architecture: x86_64
 CPUs: 2
 Total Memory: 1.943GiB
 Name: docker-desktop
 ID: NGP3:BQCE:JSUO:6BSV:IUU6:2UEZ:4QTQ:N6IO:TA3T:A7I7:4GXS:IYD6
 Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
 Debug Mode: true
  File Descriptors: 34
  Goroutines: 50
  System Time: 2020-03-27T15:56:23.690394533Z
  EventsListeners: 3
 Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
 Labels:
 Experimental: false
 Insecure Registries:
  127.0.0.0/8
 Live Restore Enabled: false
 Product License: Community Engine
```

What else can I try (short of using Docker Toolkit again) to get the integration up and running? How can I even test where the connection might be dropping?

Comment: Please report at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA with the logs attached (Help | Compress Logs and Show in ...).

Comment: @CrazyCoder will do come Monday, see if there's any help forthcoming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after three days of research, I have an answer. Apparently, Windows 10 reserves a port range of 2344-2444, which prevents the Docker daemon from *actually* exposing the TCP socket, despite the settings. I have a feeling it also relates to the daemon being unable to start after a reboot. You can verify if this is the root cause of the issue by executing the following in an elevated prompt/powershell: `netsh interface ipv4 show excludedportrange protocol=tcp` - if the output show a range that includes 2375, you *are* affected,

Remediation (this will include two reboots!):

1. Disable HyperV and reboot, to free up the port allocations: `dism.exe /Online /Disable-Feature:Microsoft-Hyper-V`
2. Manually allocate port 2375: `netsh int ipv4 add excludedportrange protocol=tcp startport=2375 numberofports=1`
3. Re-enable HyperV and reboot to take advantage of the fix: `dism.exe /Online /Enable-Feature:Microsoft-Hyper-V /All`
4. Optional: after this process, you can re-enable TLS on said socket, and the Docker plugin will be able to connect just fine.

Answer (score 0):

2 years later (June 2022), this integration is easier to setup, assuming you have the latest [Docker Desktop for Windows](https://www.docker.com/products/docker-desktop/).
It uses as a back-end either [WSL2 or HyperV](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/windows/install/).

The article "[Getting Started with Visual Studio Code and IntelliJ IDEA Docker Plugins](https://www.docker.com/blog/getting-started-with-visual-studio-code-and-intellij-idea-docker-plugins/)" from [Tyler Charboneau](https://www.linkedin.com/in/tyler-charb-writes/) details the IntelliJ IDEA part.

It will require a manual installation of the Docker plugin if you’re using the Community Edition.

> Once you’ve installed the Docker plugin, you’ll need to connect it to Docker Desktop.
>
> Follow these steps:
>
> - Navigate to `IntelliJ IDEA > Preferences`.
> - Expand the `Build, Execution, Deployment` group.
>   Click `Docker`, and then click the small "`+`" icon to the right.
> - Choose the correct Docker daemon for your platform (for example, Docker for Mac).
>
> The installation may take a few minutes. Once it’s complete, you’ll see the "`Connection successful`" message toward the middle-bottom of the `Preferences` pane:
>
> [image: https://www.docker.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/06/image2-1.png]